# Angular lazy loading module reloads application

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing

I lazy load a module. When changing the route which points to it, the whole app reloads and app.component ngOnInit() function is called again (which is undesirable since I subscribe to the server and need to do this only once). I found out that loading the module without refreshing the whole app is called 'Hot module reload' (HMR) and there are some packages that should help with that, however I would expect this to be handled by Angular itself. This issue happens only with lazy loaded modules.

**app.component.html**

```
<div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log('App init');
  this.realtimeService.subscripbeToRT(); // Should be called only once
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    {
        path: 'test',
        loadChildren: () => import('./test/test.module').then(m => m.TestModule)
    },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];

@NgModule({
      declarations: [
         ...
      ],
      imports: [
         RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
         ...
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })

  export class AppModule { }
```

In the example above, the real-time service is called on the route change to /test page. Does anyone know how to disable the whole app refresh when loading the lazy module?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show the part where you actually do the navigation to this route?

Comment: @xDrago, thank you, you pointed me in the right dirrection. Issue was that I had href on some anchor tags instead of routerLink. -_- stupid mistake.

Comment: haha, yes I thought so! :D

Answer (score 0):

can you share a plunker/stackblitz where you're doing this. the scenario described by you is unusual.

**HMR is required in development mode**. it's not used in production.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the issue was using href on some anchor tags instead of routerLinks. Now the app behaves as exprected.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, because I had  in my topbar instead of using click=goto(/blah) and in ts file do this.router.navigate(url) solved the issue